# Mysql comparison and order

Tags: mysql

I have a sql query like that

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE $maxID<=id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8
```

Here I want to retrieve rows with closest id to $maxID, however it retrieves the top 8 rows which have the biggest id, when I remove "ORDER BY id DESC" it works in other saying it retrieves the closest rows. However I do not understand the effect of "ORDER BY id DESC" here.
It should only sort the results, should not affect the retrieved results. Another problem,  does this query retrieves all rows bigger than $maxID? If it is so it is not convenient for efficiency. I do not want all rows retrieved. I want to retrieve only 8 elements. Performance is significant on my system. In this site: http://www.xarg.org/2011/10/optimized-pagination-using-mysql/   using "where x

Thanks

Comment: Please define what you mean by "closest id".

Comment: If there is ten rows with id 10,9,8,7,....1 When I query where id>5 Limit 3, I expect to the rows with id 6,7,8 will be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments you should use

```
WHERE id > $minID ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to re-order your where clause to make it easier to read.  By the logic in your query, you want all rows with ID >= $maxID.  Are you sure that's what you're looking for?

Comment: I will check code completely, probably I miss something another place of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is happining because think about what <= means, your asking for lesser or greater. When you mean closest, what are you really asking for?

Comment: What LIMIT does in the query, does not it restrict the number of results?

Comment: Yes, but it will limit to the FIRST 8 rows

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` gives you all rows matching the filter; `LIMIT` stops the filtering and returns after 8 rows. As the set is ordered by the filter criterion in descending order, it will simply give you the biggest 8 ids, since they are obviously all bigger than `$maxID`.

You may want to use a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html) to achieve your goal, e.g. something like this (untested):

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM $tbl_name WHERE $maxID<=id);
```

This query selects the 8 biggest id rows from a result set of rows where all tuples contain an id smaller or equal than `$maxID`.  These 8 rows should have the property you want: being closest or equal to `$maxID`.

Comment: Or we can use ORDER BY id ASC, isn't it?

Comment: In every web site, it is stated that  "ORDER BY" sorts the results. I still don't understand how it effects the retrieved rows. both "ORDER BY id DESC"  and "ORDER BY id DESC"  shouldn't give the same results? Why are they different?

Comment: In my table primary key is the IDs. When we use clause WHERE 5<id , doesn't it start from id=5 to retrieve rows? According to your explanation it starts from the top, which make no sense to me. If "ORDER BY id DESC" causes that, "ORDER BY" does not sort the retrieved results, it changes the retrieval mechanism of the mysql.

Comment: Yes, you can use ASC but you need to invert the filter then.  ORDER BY affects the results, as it modifies the SELECT. Your problem is combining it with a LIMIT.

Comment: Yes, now I found some documents about usage of combination of ORDER and LIMIT. I am searching it. Thank you...